# Using flex-box to align layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working on a project using where I want to achieve a layout like the one in the picture. This is what I have done so far. I am able to align the sidebar to the left and the header to the top (behind the sidebar). However I have problems aligning the contentContainer aside the sidebar and just below the topper. I was thinking of aligning the container and sidebar aside each other by width: 20% and width: 80% but the sidebar must have a fixed width size because I don't want the width to change when the app gets resized.

I also have problems within the contentContainer. I have made it a flex-box with column direction. Trying to place the headContent on flex-start, mainContent on center and footerContent on flex-end. Yet it just doesn't work. For your information, it is a reactjs app, if it is of any importance. Here is the code I have tried.

```html
       <div>
          <div className="Topbar">
            <svg viewBox="10 0 50 80">
              <text y="50">Header Text</text>
            </svg>
          </div>
    
          <div className="Sidebar">
            <svg
              id="menuitem1"
              width="70"
              height="100"
              viewBox="0 0 70 100"
              fill="#767765"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
              <path d="M22.4478 65.0703L21.7393 69.9057L26.6989 69.2151L47.1497 49.2776L42.8982 45.1328L22.4478 65.0703Z" />
              <path d="M52.0738 44.4765C53.2459 43.3339 53.2459 41.4745 52.0736 40.3317C51.506 39.7783 50.7509 39.4735 49.9482 39.4735C49.1455 39.4735 48.3904 39.7785 47.8226 40.3319L47.1487 40.9889L51.4 45.1335L52.0738 44.4765Z" />
            </svg>
            <svg
              id="menuitem2"
              width="75"
              height="78"
              viewBox="0 0 75 78"
              fill="#767765"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
              <path d="M22.4478 65.0703L21.7393 69.9057L26.6989 69.2151L47.1497 49.2776L42.8982 45.1328L22.4478 65.0703Z" />
              <path d="M52.0738 44.4765C53.2459 43.3339 53.2459 41.4745 52.0736 40.3317C51.506 39.7783 50.7509 39.4735 49.9482 39.4735C49.1455 39.4735 48.3904 39.7785 47.8226 40.3319L47.1487 40.9889L51.4 45.1335L52.0738 44.4765Z" />
          </div>
    
          <div className="contentContainer">
            <div className="headContent"/>
            <div className="mainContent">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter text here.."
                className="textBox"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="footerContent" />
          </div>
        </div>
```

And the CSS file:

```css
    .contentContainer {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      background: red;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      top: 45px;
      bottom: 50;
    }
    
    .Topbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0%;
    height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
    background:transparent;
    }
    
    svg{
      font   : bold 26px Century Gothic, Arial;
      width  : 100%;
      height : 100px;
      z-index: 3;
      filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(161, 160, 160, 0.25));
      }
    
    text{
      /* fill:  #de8356b8; */
      fill: #f0f0ec;
      stroke: rgb(40, 40, 40);
      stroke-width: 0.5px;
      stroke-linejoin: bevel;
    }
    
    
    .Sidebar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:flex-start;
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
    
    width: 80px;
    height: 100%;
    position:fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    z-index: 2;
    
    background: #faf9f9;
    /* background: transparent; */
    border-right: 0.2px solid #abababba;
    /* filter: drop-shadow(0.5px 0px 1px rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.25)); */
    }
    
    #menuitem1 {
      width: 30px;
      height: 50px;
      padding-top: 50pt;
    }
    
    #menuitem2 {
      width: 30px;
      height: 50px;
      padding-top: 30pt;
    }
    
    .textBox {
      width: 180px;
      height: 180px;
      filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(161, 160, 160, 0.25));
    }
    
    
    .Content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center ;
    
    position: fixed;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 30;
    right: 0%;
    
    background: #F8F8F8;
    }
    
    .headContent {
      width: 100%;
      height: 20%;
      align-self: flex-start;
      top: 20;
      background-color: black;
    }
    
    .mainContent {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      position: fixed;
      align-self: center;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 100%;
      height: 70%;
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    .footerContent {
      position: fixed;
      align-self: flex-end;
      align-items: flex-end;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: blue;
    }
```

Note that I want the sidebar to have a fixed width and a fixed height for the top bar. Regarding `contentContainer`, I want it to be stretched and resizable. Also, each child in `contentContainer` should have a flexbox on its own, on the row axis. You can see I have tried it in the code I provided above. I am probably close, but missing a few points here and there. Thanks for any help.

[Layout wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIyAJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, you have already done almost what you wanted. Except for an unclosed `<svg>` tag, it was all fine. The only problem is the classes. You used a `className` attribute instead of a `class` attribute. That is the main problem. If it isn't, see the picture below and tell me what else you need:

[The "picture below"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MJRu.png)

As you can see in the comments, we had a conversation and I have fixed it. So, now you need first of all to change the `className` to `class` and then you need to change your CSS file to this:

```
    body{
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .contentContainer {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: flex-start; /*start from the top and end in the bottom, for the headContainer*/
      align-items: center;
      background: red;
      width: calc(100% - 80px); /*Changed from 100%*/
      height: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      top: 45px;
      bottom: 50;
      left: 80px; /*Added to move to the right because of the sidebar*/
    }
    
    .Topbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0%;
    height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
    background:transparent;
    }
    
    svg{
      font   : bold 26px Century Gothic, Arial;
      width  : 100%;
      height : 100px;
      z-index: 3;
      filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(161, 160, 160, 0.25));
      }
    
    text{
      fill: #f0f0ec;
      stroke: rgb(40, 40, 40);
      stroke-width: 0.5px;
      stroke-linejoin: bevel;
    }
    
    
    .Sidebar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:flex-start;
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
    
    width: 80px;
    height: 100%;
    position:fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    z-index: 2;
    
    background: #faf9f9;
    border-right: 0.2px solid #abababba;
    }
    
    #menuitem1 {
      width: 30px;
      height: 50px;
      padding-top: 50pt;
    }
    
    #menuitem2 {
      width: 30px;
      height: 50px;
      padding-top: 30pt;
    }
    
    .textBox {
      width: 180px;
      height: 180px;
      filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(161, 160, 160, 0.25));
    }
    
    
    .Content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center ;
    
    position: fixed;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 30;
    right: 0%;
    
    background: #F8F8F8;
    }
    
    .headContent {
      width: 100%;
      height: 20%;
      align-self: flex-start;
      top: 20px;
      background-color: black;
      color:white;
    }
    
    .mainContent {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-self: center;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 100%;
      height: 70%;
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    .footerContent {
      position: fixed;
      align-self: flex-end;
      align-items: flex-end;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 80px;
      background-color: blue;
      color:white;
    }
```

(I hid the body's overflow-x because your content was overflowing it. If you have issues, just remove this).

Your main problem was the class attributes, but another change in your stylesheet is moving the contentContainer to the right by the sidebar's width (+padding, +margin, +border, but you didn't have any of them), which width in our case is 80 px. Then, its width needs to be 100% minus 80pixels and to justify content to flex-start, so that they can start from the top and then move to the bottom. You had done a great job, however.

Comment: But I have not, because the headContent is not showing itself beneath the topBar. In fact I cannot see it at all, when I set it's background color to black. I also want the content in the mainContent and in fact the entire contentContainer to be center to the center of the contentContainer, not the the center of the entire app itself.

Comment: Yes it is closer, yet I want the items in mainContent to be centered in the center of mainContent, and not the center of the app itself. If you guys look at the picture I uploaded then you should understand what I want

Comment: I improved it a little, but, still, do you want your input to be aligned in the center or at the bottom?

Comment: The input should be inside the mainContent, on the center of the mainContent box. Right now it is centered on the width of the complete app, but I want it to be centered on the width of only the mainContent..

Comment: Ohhhh... I see. Ok, so I have completed it and I will update my answer.

Comment: Yes you solved the problem thank you very much!

Comment: Ok, I explained exactly what I fixed. Thanks for accepting.